# Why doesn't Tomcat server start with the Eclipse although it is possible to start it manually

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have been trying to configure Eclipse to run the Tomcat 8.0.28 with Mars. When I start the server manually using the startup.bat it starts the server as expected. But when I try to run using eclipse it gives the following error.

> 'Starting Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem. 
>   The archive: /../apache-tomcat-8.0.28/bin/bootstrap.jar which is
>   referenced by the classpath, does not exist.

But when I go to,

> apache-tomcat-8.0.28/bin

it shows the **bootstrap.jar**. What am I doing wrong here? Some help is really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to google the error message? There are answers, or at least some hints what to do.

Comment: I got this [link](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-eclipse) which I thought would be helpful. But it takes too long with a message saying **Cannot perform operation. Computing alternate solutions...** If you can provide me with one of the hints, it would be a real help.

Answer (score 1):

I find the best way to debug this sort of problem is to go to the **second** line of the debug view, right click and choose properties, and then check which path is actually being used by Eclipse. Here you will see the exact command that Eclipse uses to run Tomcat.

If necessary you can then change the classpath in the "Run (or Debug) Configuration).

Right click on the second line, then choose properties
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could get it solved by removing all the projects created so far, **including server folder** and configuring the tomcat server as usual. Thanks everyone for the time taken to give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

first set the classpath.
set CATALINA=C:\apache-tomcat-5.5.29
set CLASSPATH=%CATALINA%\common\lib\servlet-api.jar;

add server when you create the Project or you can add after creating the project also.

To run your project there is an option to run on server,
when you select this option server will get started automatically